# Lighttpd - the fastcgi-backend /ffp/bin/php-cgi failed to start

Tags: telnet, lighttpd, nas

I've been trying to make my lighttpd work for almost two weeks now, but without any luck.

I have a Zyxcel 310 with FFP 0.7 running on a stick. I have transmission working on it just fine (witch includes the "curl" install) but Lighttpd will not work.

This is the error I keep getting. (If I disable fastcgi I just get 503 forbidden).

```
2013-07-02 21:12:22: (log.c.166) server started 
2013-07-02 21:12:22: (mod_fastcgi.c.1103) the fastcgi-backend /ffp/bin/php-cgi failed     to start: 
2013-07-02 21:12:22: (mod_fastcgi.c.1107) child exited with status 16 /ffp/bin/php-cgi 
2013-07-02 21:12:22: (mod_fastcgi.c.1110) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI   backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.
If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags. 
2013-07-02 21:12:22: (mod_fastcgi.c.1397) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed. 
2013-07-02 21:12:22: (server.c.945) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

I have searched al over and nobody really seems to know what is up. Some fixed the issue but there fix didn't help me.

This is what some one suggested but I also get an error here:

```
root@nsa310:~# php -i
php: can't load library 'libxml2.so.2'
```

I bought a new website last week after months of building/testing it on localhost. It is far from done yet but I tought buying it would atleast be a start. The website would be www.volunteeringnews.com "sadly still empty now".

So if someone might have an idea or an error log where I might find some more information I would be very thankfull. Anyway, here are my conf settings. (Part of it, the beginning).

```
# lighttpd configuration file
#
# use it as a base for lighttpd 1.0.0 and above
#
# $Id: lighttpd.conf,v 1.7 2004/11/03 22:26:05 weigon Exp $

############ Options you really have to take care of ####################

## modules to load
# at least mod_access and mod_accesslog should be loaded
# all other module should only be loaded if really neccesary
# - saves some time
# - saves memory
server.modules              = (
#                               "mod_rewrite",
                               "mod_redirect",
                               "mod_alias",
                                "mod_access",
#                               "mod_cml",
#                               "mod_trigger_b4_dl",
#                               "mod_auth",
#                               "mod_status",
#                               "mod_setenv",
                               "mod_fastcgi",
#                               "mod_proxy",
#                               "mod_simple_vhost",
#                               "mod_evhost",
#                               "mod_userdir",
                               "mod_cgi",
                              "mod_compress",
#                               "mod_ssi",
#                               "mod_usertrack",
#                               "mod_expire",
#                               "mod_secdownload",
#                               "mod_rrdtool",
                                "mod_accesslog" )

server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )                  

## a static document-root, for virtual-hosting take look at the
## server.virtual-* options
server.document-root        = "/mnt/HD_a2/public/website/www/"

server.upload-dirs = ( "/mnt/HD_a2/tmp" )

## where to send error-messages to
server.errorlog             = "/mnt/HD_a2/public/website/logs/error.log"

# files to check for if .../ is requested
index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                                "index.htm", "default.htm" )

## php support
## uncomment the following lines and the mod_fastcgi module above
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
    "bin-path"  => "/ffp/bin/php-cgi",
    "socket"    => "/tmp/php-cgi.socket",
    "max-procs" => 2
)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing FFP 0.7 on my NAS direcly.  :)